# js file downloads with html page but js function works only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

`parent.html : OnClick="popup();"`

**1.** page opens and displays contents
**2.** but js function isn't working. js function is defined in js file.
**3.** i checked using firebug, js file loded successfully.
**4.** it only works after refreshing the page. Any idea please? what am i making mistake?
***js function :***

```
<script>
    function popup(){
     var test = "<html><head>";
         test += "<script src= " + '"'+"jqueryTestfile.js"+'"'+ "> <" + '/' + "script>";
         test += "</head><body>";
         test += "<div id=" + '"' +"anyId" + '"' + ">";
         test += "</div>";
         test += "</body></html>"; 
     win.document.write(test);    
    }
    </script>
```

***child pop-up and source code looks like :***

```
<html> <head> 
   <script src = "jQueryTestFile.js"> </script>
 </head> <body> <div id = "anyId">
    some content here ...
 </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Have you tested using a simple alert?
If you're loading an external js file using <script src = "jQueryTestFile.js"> </script> you don't need to enclose the code within the .js file in <script></script>

Comment: @djlumley : Thanks djlumley.i'll check that. onClick on parent page then opens a child (another page) window by popup fn. this popup fn is quoted on parent page only, which opens the child window. and child window's js fn isn't working.

Comment: hey alert("hello"); is working and it defines in same js file.

Comment: So to clarify:

You have your main document. The popup function runs here with no problems.
When the popup function is run in this main document, it creates the second document. The popup function does not work in this second document until you have refreshed that window, but a function that creates an alert that's defined in the same .js file does?

Comment: @djlumley : exactly you got my question. popup function nothing to do with second document. main document's popup fn  only writes the file and populate the second document . it's second document, include a js file and this js file has several js fn that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem after a no. of attempt and would like to share :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.document.close();
</script>
```

***Why were not js functions working even after downloading the files :***  because of i was opening (pop up) a new window using `window.document.write()` and this method was causing the problem so i used `window.document.close()` to force a page to 'finish loading'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    s = document.createElement('script');

s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.onload = function () { document.getElementById('hello').innerText = h.innerText; };
s.src = 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js';
h.appendChild(s);
```

---

see:  http://jsbin.com/uhoger